# Alt answer to classic bitwise 2^n test: valid?

Tags: bit-manipulation

Quick question: I posed the single-line expression to test n for the format 2^n (n>=0).

See: http://www.exploringbinary.com/ten-ways-to-check-if-an-integer-is-a-power-of-two-in-c/

A colleague came up with this unorthodox answer:

```
((n-1) xor n == 2*n - 1) && (n != 0)
```

I built a test harness to check it, and it appears to be correct. I tested up to approx. n=10000.

Does anybody see a problem with this solution? I can't find a reference to it online.

Thanks!

-David

Comment: to check if a non-zero number is a power of 2 or not, just `(v & (v - 1)) == 0` is enough. It was posted in the famous [bithacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2) page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really test for *all* inputs (for example by using an SMT solver).

There are 31 cases in which this formula gives true even though `n` is not a power of two. They are cases where the top bit is set, in addition to some other bit. For example, 0xC0000000 or 0x80000001.

`n ^ (n - 1)` is a known way to "extract the rightmost set bit and smear it to the right". `n * 2 - 1` is accidentally the same in the cases I described, the upper bit is shifted out and the -1 smears the rightmost bit to the right (because the bit is now one to the left of where it used to be).